# How do I change the default file manager for Discord on 18.04?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

It kinda looks like hot garbage.

[image: It kinda looks like hot garbage.]

I've read that you can change Skype's default file manager, but I wouldn't know how to change it for Discord the same way you can change it for Skype. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is very likely that they are using GtkFileChooserDialog for GTK2. So it is library binding, and you can not change it. But you can find your file and other desktop file-manager and drag-and-drop it to the chat window.